# Как добавить data-attr (data-type) Symfony form конкретно в option

Tags: php, symfony, коллекции, twig, formbuilder

Структура примерно такая:

```
 $builder->add(
                $serviceName,
                'choice',
                array(
                    'placeholder' => false,
                    'required'    => false,
                    'label'       => $serviceName,
                    'help'        => $serviceName,
                    'choices'     => $list_config,
                    'expanded'    => false,
                    'multiple'    => false,
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'select_config_field',
                        'data-option0'=>'lol',
                        'data-option1'=>'noob',

                    ]
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для задания HTML атрибутов элементам используйте опцию [choice_attr](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr):

Так как версия фреймворка вами не указана, но по типу передаваемых аргументов видно что она ниже 2.8, примеры будут даны для symfony 2.7. Для использования в версиях symfony >= 2.8
необходимо использовать вместо `choice` полное имя класса (FQCN) `ChoiceType::class`.

---

Значение `choice_attr` может быть следующих типов:

#### 1. array

Подойдет в случае, если атрибуты элементов не отличаются.

```
$builder->add('field', 'choice', [
    // ...
    'choice_attr' => [
        'data-option' => 'awesome-value',
    ],
]);
```

#### 2. callable

Позволяет наиболее гибко управлять атрибутами.

```
$builder->add('field', 'choice', [
    // ...
    'choice_attr' => function ($val, $key, $index) {
        return ['data-option' => 'attending_' . $key];
    },
]);
```

#### 3. string [property path](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/form.html#reference-form-option-property-path)

Может быть использован в случае, если элементы - объекты, а значение атрибута - одно из свойств объекта:

```
$builder->add('field', 'choice', [
    // ...
    'choices' => [
        new Person('John'),
        new Person('Alice'),
        new Person('Michael'),
    ],
    'choice_attr' => 'name',
]);
```

---

### UPDATED: symfony 2.6

В этом случае использовать `choice_attr` не получится, так как он появился в версии 2.7. При этом есть несколько вариантов решения данной задачи:

- [Расширить тип `choice` реализовав `FormTypeExtensionInterface`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html)
- [Создать собственный тип реализовав `FormTypeInterface`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html)
- Кастомизировать виджет непосредственно в месте использования используя [темы](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)

Для наглядности приведу пример реализации первого варианта. Ограничусь возможностью передавать в качестве значения лишь массив атрибутов.

#### Создаем класс расширяющий тип `choice`:

```
<?php
// AppBundle/Form/Extension/ChoiceTypeExtension.php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ChoiceTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['choice_attr'] = $options['choice_attr'];
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'choice_attr' => [],
        ]);
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }
}
```

#### Регистрируем его в контейнере и присваиваем тег `form.type_extension`

```
# app/config/service.yml
services:
app.choice_type_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Extension\ChoiceTypeExtension
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, alias: choice }
```

#### Перегружаем стандартный шаблон choice_widget_options:

```
{# app/Resources/views/form_theme.html.twig #}

{%- block choice_widget_options -%}
    {%- set attr = choice_attr -%}
    {% for group_label, choice in options %}
        {%- if choice is iterable -%}
            <optgroup label="{{ group_label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}">
                {% set options = choice %}
                {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            </optgroup>
        {%- else -%}
            <option value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if attr %} {{ block('attributes') }}{% endif %}{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? choice.label : choice.label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
        {%- endif -%}
    {% endfor %}
{%- endblock -%}

{% block attributes -%}
    {%- for attrname, attrvalue in attr -%}
        {{- " " -}}
        {%- if attrname in ['placeholder', 'title'] -%}
            {{- attrname }}="{{ attrvalue|trans({}, translation_domain) }}"
        {%- elseif attrvalue is same as(true) -%}
            {{- attrname }}="{{ attrname }}"
        {%- elseif attrvalue is not same as(false) -%}
            {{- attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endblock attributes -%}
```

#### Добавляем созданный на предыдущем шаге шаблон в конфигурацию:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - "form_theme.html.twig"
```

#### Пользуемся:

```
$builder->add('gender', 'choice', [
    'required' => false,
    'choices' => [
        'm' => 'Male',
        'f' => 'Female',
    ],
    'choice_attr' => [
        'data-option' => 'awesome'
    ],
]);
```

> Код проверен на версии symfony 2.6.0

Comment: Спасибо! а если версия симфони 2.6?

Comment: @_Stein Обновил ответ: добавил пример реализации для symfony 2.6